# Continuous function from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a closed function

Tags: general-topology, compactness, closed-map

We have that $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous function, $X$ is a compact space and $Y$ is a Hausdorff space. Prove that $f$ is a closed function.

Comment: It is because a closed subset of a compact space is compact, and the image of a compact space under a continuous function is compact, and finally a compact subset of a hausdorff space is closed.  You need those three facts to prove this.

Answer (score 17):

Let $C$ be a closed subset of $X$; you want to prove that $f(C)$ is closed in $Y$.

We use three basic facts about compact spaces:

1. a closed subset of a compact space is compact;
2. the image of a compact subset under a continuous function is compact;
3. a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Now the proof of your statement.

Since $X$ is compact, $C$ is compact as well; therefore $f(C)$ is compact. A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed. Hence $f(C)$ is closed.

Comment: @Sokkun: In a similar way, you can prove that such a map is *proper*, meaning that the preimage of a compact set is compact.

Comment: +1   very  nice  answer@egreg