# Embedding $D^k \to S^n$ is a closed map?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $k,n$ be positive integers, and suppose $h:D^k \to S^n$ is an embedding. Then is the image $h(D^k)$ closed in $S^n$?

I know that embedding is not in general a closed map, but in this special case, it seems true, but I'm not sure.

I thought about this question while reading the proof of the Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem (Proposition 2B.1 in Hatcher)

Comment: Can you remind us what $D^k$ is please.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, $D^k$ is the $k$-dimensional closed unit disk.

Comment: have a look at this question and it's answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327685/continuous-function-from-a-compact-space-to-a-hausdorff-space-is-a-closed-functi

Comment: The image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact.

Comment: Oh my god, it was too trivial

Comment: Note that compact sets are closed only in a Hausdorff setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

If $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous map and $C \subset X$ is compact, then $f(C)$ is compact. Thus if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f(C)$ is closed.